# how to change the source of a picture by the outcome of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, forms

I made a menu with multiple checkboxes and radio forms. When the visitor selects his choices I need a script to show which option he chose. There is only one option possible and there are over 500 choices. Can I use the outcome of the checkboxes to change the source of the image using java?
[image: structure]
RadioForm1:
Size

Small
Medium (selected)
Large

Radioform2:
Color:
Blue
Green 
Red
Yellow (selected)
Orange

src:Images/medium/yellow/img.png

Comment: when you have radio buttons, the bullet shows which one is selected, maybe you want to do something more advanced?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Comment: Yes, im looking for a way to get the script get the outcome of the different radio forms en paste it into the source of the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rf4nZ/)

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() {
    var colors = $( '.color' ),
        sizes  = $( '.size' ),
        img    = $( '#image' ),
        changeHandler = function( evt ){
            var path = [ 'Images', sizes.filter(':checked').val(), colors.filter(':checked').val(), 'img.png' ].join('/');
            img.attr( 'src', path );
//            img.attr( 'alt', path );
            console.log( path );
        };
    colors.on( 'change', changeHandler );
    sizes .on( 'change', changeHandler )
          .change();
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Color</legend>
    <div>
        <input class="color" name="color" value="Red" id="color_red" checked="checked" type="radio">
        <label for="color_red">Red</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="color" name="color" value="Yellow" id="color_yellow" type="radio">
        <label for="color_yellow">Yellow</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="color" name="color" value="Blue" id="color_blue" type="radio">
        <label for="color_blue">Blue</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Size</legend>
    <div>
        <input class="size" name="size" value="Small" id="size_small" checked="checked" type="radio">
        <label for="size_small">Small</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="size" name="size" value="Medium" id="size_medium" type="radio">
        <label for="size_medium">Medium</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="size" name="size" value="Large" id="size_large" type="radio">
        <label for="size_large">Large</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<img id="image" src="Images/Small/Red/img.png" height="100px" width="100px">
</body></html>
```

Comment: Great! thanks a lot MT0! Its exactly what i was looking for. Your really helping me out with this!